# Read and Write CSV using fast-csv package in Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to write a simple node program that reads a csv file, extracts a column (say second) and writes it to another CSV file. I am reading the contents to an array and then writing that array to file.

Stages and data in each step

**inputfile**

```
123,456,789,abc
def,ghi,232,jkl
```

**array**

```
['456','ghi']
```

**outputfile**

```
4,5,6
g,h,i
```

**output needed**

```
456
ghi
```

Am i just missing a configuration or is the way i am writing data wrong? Is my block of code to write to file within END block not correct?

Here is my code

```
var fast_csv = require('fast-csv');
var tempArray=new Array();
console.log("START");
fast_csv.fromPath("inputfile.txt").on("data", function(data){
    tempArray.push(data[1]);  
})
  .on("end", function(){
    tempArray.sort();
    console.log(tempArray);

    fast_csv.writeToPath("outputfile.csv", tempArray)
   .on("finish", function(){
      console.log("END");
   });

});
```

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: Their examples are trash

Answer (score 4):

It treats each element in the array as an array, so '456' is treated as an array with the elements 4,5,6.

A strange workaround I did was to loop through the array and put each element inside its own array, so it would be:

```
var newArray = [];

 for( var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
 var arr = [];
 arr.push(tempArray[i]);
newArray.push(arr);
}
```

And then write the "newArray".

But otherwise if you write row by row, you can put each element inside a bracket, like:

```
var fast_csv = fastcsv.createWriteStream();
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("outputfile.csv");
fast_csv.pipe(writeStream);

for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
    fast_csv.write( [ tempArray[i]  ] );             //each element inside bracket
    }
fast_csv.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `tempArray.push(data[1]);` to: `tempArray.push([data[1]]);`

`writeToPath` takes an array of arrays.

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv