# How to read and write data from csv using fast csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am reading data from a csv and transforming the data.
Now i want to write the data to a new csv but the file is getting created but the data is not getting populated.

here is what i have tried

```
const fs = require('fs');
var csv = require("fast-csv");

var stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/rahul/Downloads/it.csv");
var ws = fs.createWriteStream("/home/rahul/Downloads/my.csv");

csv
 .fromStream(stream)
 .transform(function(data){
    return data.map(function(ip) {
        return Number(
            ip.split(".")
              .map(d => ("000"+d).substr(-3) )
              .join("")
          );   
    })

 })
 .on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data); // this logs [ 5009000000, 5009255255 ]
 })
 .on("end", function(data){
    csv.write(data).pipe(ws);

 });
```

Comment: https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905140/read-and-write-csv-using-fast-csv-package-in-node-js ?